# typo3 remove session data of fe-user

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Hi I have an typo3 extension that stores data in session.

After my actions are finished I want to remove the session data.

I tried this:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->removeSessionData();
```

But this does not work.

What is my fail? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

```
        if ( is_null($GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->getKey("ses", "Step1")) ) {
            $this->redirect('noProductFound');
        }

        $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
        $reloadPage = new \TYPO3\ShopExtension\Controller\ShopStep();
        $product = $arguments['product'];

        $orderProcessed = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'orderProcessed');

        #Verhindern das Seite neu geladen wird und eine neue Bestellung getätigt wird.
        if ($reloadPage->getReload() == true | $orderProcessed == true) {
            $this->redirect('noProductFound', null, null, array('error' => 'orderProcessed'));
        } else {
            if ($product == ShopConstant::AG_TRIAL) {
                $this->save_Product_Trial();
                $reloadPage->setReload(true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'orderProcessed', true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
            } elseif ($product == ShopConstant::AG_PROFESSIONELL || $product == ShopConstant::AG_PREMIUM || $product == ShopConstant::AG_ULTIMATE) {
                $afterOrderOrderId = $this->save_Product_Auditgarant($product);
                $reloadPage->setReload(true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'orderProcessed', true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
            } elseif ($product == ShopConstant::BOOK_AL || $product == ShopConstant::BOOK_PH || $product == ShopConstant::BOOK_CPMS || $product == ShopConstant::BOOK_USABILITY) {
                $this->save_Product_Book($product);
                $reloadPage->setReload(true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'orderProcessed', true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
            } elseif ($product == ShopConstant::INSTITUTSTAG || $product == ShopConstant::INSTITUTSTAG_PARTNER || $product == ShopConstant::INSTITUTSTAG_ALUMNI) {
                $this->save_Product_Institutstag($product);
                $reloadPage->setReload(true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'orderProcessed', true);
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
            } else {
                $this->redirect('noProductFound');
            }
            #Session löschen, da Daten ab hier nicht mehr benötigt werden.
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->removeSessionData();
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'Step1', null);
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
//            \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($GLOBALS['TSFE']);
//            exit();
            #Führt einen redirect durch mit angehängtem Attribut des letzten Step.
            $this->redirect('getContent', null, null, array(
                'step' => $arguments['lastStep'],
                'shopStep' => $arguments['product'],
                'afterOrderOrderId' => $afterOrderOrderId
            ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you did `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('session_key', $somevalue);` you can simply do `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('session_key', null);` to delete the session data.

Comment: tried, but has no effect. when I reload the page the data is still present. also tried this

`$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'Step1', null);
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();`

Comment: I need more of your code then to be able to reproduce your issue

Comment: any further hints?

Comment: @Felix could you check what value your session contains when you check it in your first if-statement? The mentioned solutions should work.