# How to delete a session in TYPO3?

Tags: session, typo3

How can I delete a session in TYPO3?

I have tried like this
`$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'myData', NULL);`

But the session wasn't deleted.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445116/typo3-remove-session-data-of-fe-user?answertab=active#tab-top) is the answer you're looking for, This will lead you to the solution I guess.

Comment: Yes it's worked

Comment: Cool... Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('session_key', null);